# SELECT contant value is Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I'm trying to do a simple select in Cassandra CQL3 containing a hardcoded value (constant) under a constant column name and I simply can't get it working

Here's the query

`SELECT 1 as "id"`

Works fine in all kinds of DBMS I use but throws this error here:

`Error: ResponseError: line 1:7 no viable alternative at input '1' (SELECT [1]...)`

What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, CQL is not SQL, and queries like this do not work in cqlsh as they do in their relational counterparts.  The DataStax [SELECT documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html) indicates that a selector must be one of:

1. column name
2. WRITETIME (column name)
3. TTL (column name)
4. function

Now while a `SELECT 1 as id` query may not work, there are other, slightly more useful things that do.  For instance, if I need to quickly generate a UUID, I can do so with the following query:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT uuid() FROM system.local;

 system.uuid()
--------------------------------------
 a55c17f7-d19d-4531-85be-75551e3fd546

(1 rows)
```

This works the way it does for two reasons:

1. The SELECT clause invokes the uuid() function.
2. The system.local table only ever contains a single row.  If you ran this SELECT against another table, it would return as many UUIDs as there were CQL rows.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sadly this won't help in what I'm trying to achieve. My use case is simple, I need to link queries made against multiple DBMS to an external ID. Works fine is SQL and even in MongoDB, not here.

Seems like I have two choices, store a table containing dumb hardcoded IDs or get the ID out of the query

Answer (score 2):

I have found an extraordinarily icky way to do this.

```
SELECT blobAsBigInt(bigintAsBlob(1)) AS c FROM table;
```

will give you a constant column of value 1. If you want to try this all by itself, make sure to

```
SELECT blobAsBigInt(bigintAsBlob(1)) AS c FROM table LIMIT 1;
```

or you will never hear the end of it.

Comment: Doesn't work. I always get "No viable input after (" error with this example.